# ¿Como agregar un efecto de transision a un sidebar cuando este se muestra y oculta?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

estoy teniendo problemas, mejor dicho, no tengo idea de cómo agregar un efecto de transición cuando se oculta/muestra el sidebar ya que se ve muy rápido y no es agradable visualmente, se encuentra ubicado en la parte derecha del monitor.

Para ocultar / mostrar el menu (boton sidebar)  lo estoy haciendo mediante css grid y una variable booleana,
si está abierto aplicale la clase ".opened" a div principal

Por favor ejecutar el Código en pantalla completa.
Creo que el problema se encuentra en el display none pero no sé, ya no sé qué hacer.

**abierto( con sidebar )**
div pricipal

```
<div class="container" :class="{ opened: isOpen }">
...
codigo html
...
</div>
```

codigo css:

```
.container {
  max-width: 1920px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr) 260px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header sidebar"
    "content content sidebar"
    "footer footer sidebar";
}
```

**abierto( sin sidebar)**

```
.opened {
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header"
    "content content content"
    "footer footer footer";
    aside {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```js
const application = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            isOpen: false,
        }
    },
    template: `
    <div class="container" :class="{ opened: isOpen }">
    <header>
      <div class="top-navbar">
        <div class="titles">
          <button @click="isOpen = !isOpen">
            <i class="fas fa-bars">sidebar</i>
          </button>
        </div>
        <nav>
          <ul id="items">
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="btn"><i class="fas fa-bell"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="btn">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="btn">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="btn">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="btn">About</a></li>
            <li>
              <button class="btn"><i class="fas fa-exchange-alt"></i></button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="navigation">
        <a href="" class="CompanyName"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Company Name Here</a> >
      </div>
    </header>
    <main>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="box">
            <div class="box-title">
              <h1>Log de sessiones</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="box-content">
              Hola @nombreDeusuario
              <br />

              <table id="customers">
                <tr>
                  <th>Direccion IP</th>
                  <th>Ingreso de sesion</th>
                  <th>hora</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>200.43.455.24</td>
                  <td>15/01/2021</td>
                  <td>11:45 a.m.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>200.43.455.2</td>
                  <td>14/01/2021</td>
                  <td>01:45 a.m.</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td>200.43.455.2</td>
                  <td>13/01/2021</td>
                  <td>08:25 a.m.</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td>200.43.455.2</td>
                  <td>12/01/2021</td>
                  <td>7:22 a.m.</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td>200.43.455.2</td>
                  <td>11/01/2021</td>
                  <td>09:16d a.m.</td>
                </tr>
              </table>

              <div class="buttons-right">
                <button class="btn">Ver</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="box">
            <div class="box-title">
              <h1>Contenido</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="box-content"></div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </main>
    <aside>
      <div class="navbar">
        <div class="avatar">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="" srcset="" />
        </div>
        <div class="name">
          <p>Lic. Maria G</p>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
          <button>Link 1</button>
          <button>Link x</button>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="" class="link"><i class="fas fa-home space-i">Home</i></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="" class="link"><i class="fas fa-users space-i">Employees</i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="" class="link">Accounts</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="" class="link">Employees</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </aside>
    <footer>
      <h3>© 2019 Company Name. All rights reserved.</h3>
    </footer>
  </div>
    `,
});
application.mount("#app");
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  color: #000;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
      align-content: center;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1920px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: (1fr)[2] 260px;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr) 260px;
  -ms-grid-rows: (auto)[3];
      grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
      grid-template-areas: "header header sidebar"
 "content content sidebar"
 "footer footer sidebar";
}

.opened {
      grid-template-areas: "header header header"
 "content content content"
 "footer footer footer";
}

.opened aside {
  display: none;
}

header {
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 3;
  grid-area: header;
}

main {
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 3;
  grid-area: content;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
}

main ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.box .box-title {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(26, 54, 126, 0.125);
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.box .box-content {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

aside {
  background-color: white;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 3;
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
  grid-area: sidebar;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s;
  transition: width 2s;
}

footer {
  background-color: grey;
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 3;
  grid-area: footer;
  height: 150px;
}

.top-navbar {
  font-weight: 800;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0053ac), to(#0053ac));
  background-image: linear-gradient(#0053ac, #0053ac);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
          box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  height: 55px;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.top-navbar nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.top-navbar nav ul li {
  margin: 6px;
}

.navigation {
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.navigation .CompanyName {
  color: black;
}

.navbar {
  -webkit-transition: margin-right 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: margin-right 2s ease-in-out;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0053ac), to(#0053ac));
  background-image: linear-gradient(#0053ac, #0053ac);
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.navbar ul li {
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin: 5px;
  border: black solid 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.navbar ul li i {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.space-i::before {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

/* unvisited link */
a:link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
  color: white;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
  color: white;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
  color: white;
}

#customers {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#customers td,
#customers th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#customers tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#customers th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0053ac), to(#0053ac));
  background-image: linear-gradient(#0053ac, #0053ac);
  color: white;
}

.buttons-right {
  margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
      -ms-flex-pack: end;
          justify-content: flex-end;
}

.btn {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #01438a;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>CDN en Vue 3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <Layout />
    </div>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si cambias la estructura completa de tu página web, no podrás hacer transiciones con css.

Actualmente cada vez que presionas el botón sidebar, estás redefiniendo la estructura de tu página con grid-template-areas, y eso no lo puedes animar con css. Por otro lado, incluso corrigiendo eso, tampoco puedes animar utilizando la propiedad display.

Una posible solución es sacar la sidebar del container y ponerla al mismo nivel que el container. Luego los encierras en un flex div que los ponga uno al lado del otro. Cuando se muestre la barra lateral, tendrá su ancho normal de 260px y cuando se oculte, tendrá un ancho de cero. Le agregamos una transición y listo.

Te adjunto mi solución:

```js
const application = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            isOpen: false,
        }
    },
    template: `
    <div class="mainContainer">
    <div class="container">
    <header>
      <div class="top-navbar">
        <div class="titles">
          <button @click="isOpen = !isOpen">
            <i class="fas fa-bars">sidebar</i>
          </button>
        </div>
        <nav>
          <ul id="items">
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="btn"><i class="fas fa-bell"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="btn">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="btn">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="btn">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="btn">About</a></li>
            <li>
              <button class="btn"><i class="fas fa-exchange-alt"></i></button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="navigation">
        <a href="" class="CompanyName"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Company Name Here</a> >
      </div>
    </header>
    <main>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="box">
            <div class="box-title">
              <h1>Log de sessiones</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="box-content">
              Hola @nombreDeusuario
              <br />

              <table id="customers">
                <tr>
                  <th>Direccion IP</th>
                  <th>Ingreso de sesion</th>
                  <th>hora</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>200.43.455.24</td>
                  <td>15/01/2021</td>
                  <td>11:45 a.m.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>200.43.455.2</td>
                  <td>14/01/2021</td>
                  <td>01:45 a.m.</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td>200.43.455.2</td>
                  <td>13/01/2021</td>
                  <td>08:25 a.m.</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td>200.43.455.2</td>
                  <td>12/01/2021</td>
                  <td>7:22 a.m.</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td>200.43.455.2</td>
                  <td>11/01/2021</td>
                  <td>09:16d a.m.</td>
                </tr>
              </table>

              <div class="buttons-right">
                <button class="btn">Ver</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="box">
            <div class="box-title">
              <h1>Contenido</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="box-content"></div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </main>
    
    <footer>
      <h3>© 2019 Company Name. All rights reserved.</h3>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <aside class="" :class="{ opened: isOpen }">
      <div class="navbar">
        <div class="avatar">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="" srcset="" />
        </div>
        <div class="name">
          <p>Lic. Maria G</p>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
          <button>Link 1</button>
          <button>Link x</button>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="" class="link"><i class="fas fa-home space-i">Home</i></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="" class="link"><i class="fas fa-users space-i">Employees</i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="" class="link">Accounts</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="" class="link">Employees</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </aside>
    </div>
    `,
});
application.mount("#app");
```

```css
.mainContainer{
display: flex;
position: relative;
width: calc(100% + 260px);
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  color: #000;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
      align-content: center;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  overflow-X: hidden;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1920px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: (1fr)[2];
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  -ms-grid-rows: (auto)[3];
      grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
      grid-template-areas: "header header"
 "content content"
 "footer footer";
 width: 100%;
}


.opened{
  margin-right:260px;
}

header {
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 3;
  grid-area: header;
}

main {
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 3;
  grid-area: content;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
}

main ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.box .box-title {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(26, 54, 126, 0.125);
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.box .box-content {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

aside {
  background-color: white;
  width: 260px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 1s;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-right:0;
}

footer {
  background-color: grey;
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 3;
  grid-area: footer;
  height: 150px;
}

.top-navbar {
  font-weight: 800;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0053ac), to(#0053ac));
  background-image: linear-gradient(#0053ac, #0053ac);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
          box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  height: 55px;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.top-navbar nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.top-navbar nav ul li {
  margin: 6px;
}

.navigation {
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.navigation .CompanyName {
  color: black;
}

.navbar {
  -webkit-transition: margin-right 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: margin-right 2s ease-in-out;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0053ac), to(#0053ac));
  background-image: linear-gradient(#0053ac, #0053ac);
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.navbar ul li {
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin: 5px;
  border: black solid 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.navbar ul li i {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.space-i::before {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

/* unvisited link */
a:link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
  color: white;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
  color: white;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
  color: white;
}

#customers {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#customers td,
#customers th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#customers tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#customers th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0053ac), to(#0053ac));
  background-image: linear-gradient(#0053ac, #0053ac);
  color: white;
}

.buttons-right {
  margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
      -ms-flex-pack: end;
          justify-content: flex-end;
}

.btn {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #01438a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>CDN en Vue 3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <Layout />
    </div>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No sé quién te ha votado en negativo ni por qué, la verdad, no te lo mereces en absoluto. La solución que propones es sencilla y limpia. ;)

Comment: Gracias @Bettylex. Yo tampoco tengo idea la razón del voto. Mi solución resuelve lo que se pide, incluso puede ejecutarse, pero bueno, cada cual tendrá sus razones, lástima que no comparta su opinión.

Comment: No sabia nada de lo que me dijiste gracias!, buena tu solucion pero preferi hacerlo mas facil aun , agrege un bind class al div del sidebar lo saque al mismo nivel del container, lo posisiono con position fixed, left 0px top 0px 
modifico los margenes del tama;o del aside y listo, gracias !.

Pero mi duda fue resuelta, ya se como aplicar la transision de forma correcta!
Gracias!

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido @Maria. Yo también lo pensé con fixed, pero como lo habías implementado en tu ejemplo, modificabas el ancho del container cuando aparecia el sidebar. Con fixed, el ancho no se modificará,  la barra lateral quedará encima del contenido, por eso me decanté por esta última. De cualquier forma, me alegro que hayas encontrado solución a tu problema. Saludos!